# calculating sum and dealing with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a problem with the rowSum function. What's happening is that any rows with NAs are being counted as 0 and I don't want that. Here is my data:

```
V1 V2 V3   V4
1  0  0    1
0  1  NA   1
NA  NA NA  NA
```

Here is what is happening:

```
V1 V2 V3   V4  SUM
1  0  0    1    2
0  1  NA   1    2
NA  NA NA  NA   0
```

I want this:

```
V1 V2 V3   V4  SUM
1  0  0    1    2
0  1  NA   1    2
NA  NA NA  NA   NA
```

I've looked on several websites and I have tried so many different iterations of code and I keep getting the same thing. This is the most basic piece of code I have used, although I tried using dplyr. Can someone please help me?

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df, na.rm = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that

```
NA ^ 0
#[1] 1
NA ^ 1
#[1] NA
```

Using it in `rowSums`, we can do :

```
rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA^(rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0)
#[1]  2  2 NA
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! I don't understand the carrot. Also, I don't think it quite worked.

Comment: It works for the example you provided. Did you assign the value? `df$sum <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA^(rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0)`.

Comment: I did. Is there something I could do to give you a better sense of my data? there are more variables and i'm not sure if that would matter. Thanks in advance, Ronak. :)

Comment: What output do you get? Or do you receive an error? In this example we are taking sum of all the columns in `df`, if in your real data you want to take sum of only selected columns you should subset the data accordingly. For example, to remove 1st column from calculation do `rowSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE) * NA^(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) == 0)` Or to select only columns `2:4` `rowSums(df[2:4], na.rm = TRUE) * NA^(rowSums(!is.na(df[2:4])) == 0)`. Does that help?

Comment: Actually, your solution did end up working--thank you!